# Pointers, links, object and reference count

Tags: java

```
String a = "a"; // allocate memory and write address of a memory block to a variable
String b = "b";

// a and b hold addresses

b = a; // copy a address into b. 

// Now what? b value is completely lost and will be garbage collected

//*** next step


a = null; // now a does not hold a valid address to any data, 

// still data of a object exist somewhere, yet we cannot get access to it.
```

Correct me if there's a mistake somewhere in my reflexions.

My question is:

suppose anInstance object of type Instance has a property ' surname '
anInstance.getSurname() returns "MySurname".

```
now String s = anInstance.getSurname();
anInstance = null;
```

question is - is it true that getSurname value, namely MySurname
will not be garbage collected because and only because
it has active reference
counter > 0, and if other properties of anInstance 
have a zero reference counter, they'll be
garbage collected?

Comment: (To be a confusing pedant, literal (and *compile time constant*) Strings are "interned" and not allocated whilst executing the code. Effectively they are part of the code and are garbage collected at the same time as the code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java uses a garbage collection algorithm that's much more sophisticated than a simple reference count.

Yes, it's possible for anInstance and any objects it references to be GC'd, which surname is not.  Whether or not this happens depends on scope and other factors that you don't describe.  I don't think your question gives enough context to allow a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 4):

`MySurname` will not be garbage collected because it has an active reference, `s`, but there is no reference count as such. Java's garbage collector doesn't rely on reference counting.

Comment: I suppose there's 'cause it is decremented every time next link is broken. When it is zero, it can be garbage collected.

Comment: @EugeneP - how will cyclic references will be GCed then?

Comment: Ok, you are right. It is out of the scope of the question, GC algorithm.